# Synchronize a local android database via node / express js

Tags: android, mysql, node.js, sqlite, express

I have read many tutorials and answers to questions about this same situation, but in each of them we refer to the use of scripts or in any case queries through PHP, but none satisfies my situation.
Let me explain my situation, I have a CRUD app and a MySQL database on a node js server, I'm going to connect an android app to the same database on the server, taking advantage of a local SQLite database, so my questions are as follows.

Can I sync my android app or better my SQLite database through the same express js queries I make to my database through my web app?

To help you better understand my question, I have typical queries made through such functions:

```
exports.listU = function(req, res){

  req.getConnection(function(err,connection){

    var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM user',function(err,rows)
    {
        if(err)
            console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );

        res.render('user',{page_title:"users view",data:rows});  

     });

  });

};
```

Can I use it, maybe using it in a simpler context than what I'm using to display my user list on the browser, to get a JSON or something like that? I thought of building a simple HTML screen that shows the result of this query on video, without buttons, images and more, so as to have a JSON file as easy as possible, and avoiding this screen, appear in the router of my web app.

I'm also open to other solutions, as long as they do not plan to use other languages, such as PHP, I would like to stay as much as possible within these languages (android, node/express, javascript).

**[EDIT]** Would it be possible to send the query result via a JSON through something like that?

```
...
res.send(JSON.stringify(rows))
...
```

to be able to read it as a result directly from the android app?

**[solved]** 
Maybe this can help someone in my same situation. The approach was not very different from what I was thinking, using a javascript very similar to the previous one, with the difference that instead of doing the rendering I sent the result of the query through something like * res.send (JSON.stringify ({"response": rows})); * I was able to view a json of the database. Once I did this I simply "connected" (via *HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL (URL) .openConnection ();*) and authentication with my android app, I later managed the json file displayed on the screen by executing the split of it and updating the fields of my internal SQLite database to the android app, through a local insert query. I recommend, when updating the internal database, each time to delete and recreate the tables in the local sqlite database to avoid duplication problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to use CouchDB framework, that enable fast sync databases.
This alternative much better then using separate DBs such as: mysql or SQLite.
Also, the object between interface is JSON that will provide you with a flexibility in the future to use external frameworks.
CouchDB works with NodeJS - with npm nano framework.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I took a look at what you proposed, but I'm afraid that I still have to change my MySQL server if I use CouchDB, or there is a way to use CouchDB only instead of SQLite android side?

Comment: CouchDB is a Database, instead of use SQLite or mysql,  you can use the framework for both side client and server sides, the interaction  between them is by JSON.